# Write a new adapter about gridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am going to write a Gadapter(extends Baseadapter)  for GridView,but this code has stopped when I run this app.Is there anyone can help me?

logo.xml have 1 Textview and 1 ImageView.

MY GADAPTER:

```
 public class Gadapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Gadapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.logo,null);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText(position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: post log cat's error then anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly set inflate the view with the parents layout params by passing using the three arg `inflate()` method.

You can only reference your `TextView t` from the `convertView`.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.logo,parent, false);
        TextView t=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText(position);
        return convertView;
    }
```